# Displaying dynamically generated images in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm writing my first Yesod app.
The application involves the user selecting to view a graph, dynamically generated based on data stored in a DB on the server.
I know how to get the user request and create the image on the server's file system, but how do I create a response page presenting it?

P.S. As I'm using GnuPlot to generate the image, I only know how to write it as a file to the file system, but If you happen to know how to get the data in memory it'll probably be even better.
Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a file on disk, you can use [`sendFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.2.12/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v%3asendFile) in your handler.

```
getImageR = do
    -- ... save image data to disk somewhere
    sendFile typeJpeg "/path/to/file.jpg"
```

For sending it from a `ByteString` in memory, use [`sendResponse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.2.12/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v%3asendResponse).

```
getImageR = do
    bytes <- -- generate image data
    sendResponse (typePng, toContent bytes)
```

Make sure you specify the [correct content type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.2.12/docs/Yesod-Core-Content.html#t%3aContentType) for your image.

Comment: I actually think you could just use "return" instead of sendResponse in this case, since you don't need any short-circuiting. Also, remember to use liftIO if you're using normal IO functions.