# Generate server sided images (QR codes) and display them on a page with Yesod

Tags: haskell, qr-code, yesod

I'd like to be able to generate arbitrary qr codes and display them on a web page, which will be served by Yesod.

I don't really have any code to share because I don't know how I would go about linking up the QR code generating / diagramming libraries there are and then outputting an image that can be served on the page.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/qrcode

Comment: This one is probably better: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-qrcode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-qrcode) package for generating qr codes. The images can be sendt to the client with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147799/displaying-dynamically-generated-images-in-yesod) method.

The [diagrams-rasterific](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-rasterific) package can probably be used to create a `ByteString` which can be sent to the client.

Use the [renderDrawing](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Rasterific-0.6.1/docs/Graphics-Rasterific.html#g:7) function with the [encodePng](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.2.7/docs/Codec-Picture-Png.html) function from the [JuicyPixles](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels) package to create the `ByteString` which you can send to the client using [sendResponse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.2.12/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v%3asendResponse)